# Horrific beginner mistake using OpenZFS

Tags: linux, zfs

This was my first time using ZFS and I made a huge blunder.

I created my "server" zpool as per:

```
sudo zpool create -f server raidz2 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde
```

Then, there was a directory under my root directory called `/server`.

So I changed the permission in the folder so I could write to it and created two folders in `/server` then dumped several portable HDD & SSDs into the folders then went to bed. I estimate about 300-600 GB worth.

The next day I went into `/server` and it was empty! I looked at the properties and it says usage 404.8 GiB of 437 GiB free. When I typed `ls -l` there is nothing in the folder (the pool was comprised of four 8 TB drives).

I think I needed to create a dataset to save the data under, rather than the top level of the zpool, big whoops!

I tried Testdisk on the effected portable hard drives and I think the data is still on them but the file structure is not restorable with Testdisk?

So now my big issue is I can't spend hundreds of hours sorting random files out, I have a fourth child imminent and no spare time. So I was really hoping to find a ZFS solution in restoring the misplaced data as I think it's my only practicable option. I'm hoping it's still on the ZFS drives somewhere. Without the file structure the data is almost useless. Otherwise I'd try and restore the data with Testdisk from the portable drives.

Comment: Define more precisely the EXACT action you took when you  'dumped  several portable HDD & SSDs into the folders'. Hopefully you did not 'move' the data, but copied it. Also hopefully you did not use a gui file manager to do this, but used a command line. I'm not going to hope you used rsync to do it, which is what you should have done, and you already feel bad enough as it is, but do add very precise, exact, details, leave nothing out about what you exactly did when you transferred the data. '
'dumped into' is not a technical term and does not help illuminate your issue.

Comment: Just as a general observation, the actual error you made was not simply taking one file and copying to your zfs array and checking that it was all good before doing anything else. Not trying to rub salt in the wound, just noting that is a basic procedure you always do to test something like this before engaging in any large operation.

Comment: It sounds like you did not create a zfs file system or mount it, but why that was showing in your file manager I don't exactly understand, I'm not fully up on zfs but what you explained doesn't quite make sense unless your file manager did something bad. I think it's probably relevant what operating system you are using too. Be precise, what file manager are you using, what OS, the lack of these details is worrying since they matter. A proper OS should not have allowed this event to occur, unless the file manager was trying to be too clever for your own good.

Comment: You **should** create dataset(s) in your zpool (rather than just put data into the top-level of the pool directly), but you don't have to.  The top level of a pool **is** a dataset.  My guess as to what's happened is that you shutdown the machine and didn't import the pool or mount any filesystems (datasets) on it when you rebooted (maybe you didn't update your initramfs or startup scripts to do that).   Try `zpool import server` or `zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-id/`. 
 and/or maybe `zfs mount server` too.

Comment: @Lizardx, I did exactly all the things you hoped I didn't. The mistakes I made were: Using the file manager (Thunar), MOVING rather than copying, not using Rsync and not checking that things were okay. I am using MX Linux, which is based off Debian 10.

Comment: @cas The weirdest thing has happened, I booted up again to try what you suggested and my background had changed to the XFCE one with the mouse on it, there was a Rubbish Bin Icon on the top left of the screen and a file system icon below that. I didn't think I'd made any other User accounts on the OS but when I went into /server the folders were there! I'm seriously confused as to what is happening. I also should have mentioned that when I went to the properties of /server I made the Access: Read & Write and the Group: Rob. I just remembered and thought that might be relevant. Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming when you click on 'server' you are mounting the zfs dataset in thunar.I can't guess as to what is going on with your login unless you logged in as root once, that would explain some of it, the previous time. The reason to use rsync -a is so that the data is copied cleanly, and if anything interrupts the transfer, rsync will just start over where it left off unlike a gui or cp operation. You were lucky. But NEVER 'move' data between devices when it involves a lot of data, that's how you lose data. copy/rsync always, so if something goes wrong, the original data is untouched.

Comment: Note that you have to mount the dataset /server explicitly in /etc/fstab for it to be there as expected always, thunar is quite good about finding and presenting things that could be mounted, like new usb block devices, etc, but that's not the same as actually mounting the data correctly. The desktop changing is worrisome unless you did an upgrade at some point, or mx ran one and it updated xfce, and then when you rebooted that updated default appeared again. If you reboot and /server is not filled when checking on command line with ls /server, it's not mounted.

Comment: inxi -Rdpo will show you all the data you need to see for this situation, -R will show the zfs whether it's mounted or not, -d will show all drives, -p will show you the mounted partitions, and -o will show you unmounted.

Comment: Hi Lizardx, sorry about the late reply, I had to write a job application (nothing to do with ZFS fortunately, ha ha). Okay, well I don't think I updated, and it's not connected to the internet. I also don't think it's mounted in fstab, because there is only two lines, one is ext4 which I assume is the OS and the other is a UUID=... swap swap defaults 0 0 which I assume is for hibernating? Running inxi -Rdpo is interesting: Local storage 29.55tb, ID-1 is the OS, IDs 2 to 5 are the drives I used for the ZFS.  RAID Device-1: server type zfs STATUS online SIZE 29tb Partition 2 & 3 are ZFS related.

Comment: Ran out of characters, to continue: Any advice as to what steps I can do to be confident to use the ZFS pool? I don't remember reading anything about modifying the fstab for the zpool? Thanks heaps in advance!!

Comment: You don't need to edit `/etc/fstab` for zfs as zfs manages its own mounts (via the `mounted`, `mountpoint`, and `canmount` properties).   Try running `zfs get all server | grep mount` to see what these properties are for your `server` dataset.  You need to have a `mountpoint` set, and you need `canmount=on` to have it automount at boot (this is the default, unless you've changed it. or unless it inherits a different setting from a parent dataset).   `mounted` tells you its current status. See also `man zfsprops` (or just `man zfs` in older versions of zfs) and search for those properties.

Comment: Alternatively, you can list the properties you want instead of just "all": `zfs get mounted,mountpoint,canmount server`. You'll see the column headers that way, too.   See `man zfs-get` or just `man zfs` for details on the `get` sub-command.    BTW, `zpool` also has a `get` sub-command to show the properties of a pool rather than a dataset.   And, of course, `get` has a correspinding `set` option.  e.g. `zfs set canmount=on server` or `zfs set mountpoint=/server server`.   You can mount that particular dataset with `zfs mount server` (or `zfs mount -a` if it has `canmount=on`).

Comment: Thanks very much for the comments cas. I booted up again earlier today and was back to the initial empty /server. Running zpool status: no pools available. Running inxi -Rdpo again said no RAID status and the ID-1 to 8 which are the four drives, were 'Unmounted'.
I just re-booted and it was working again, so I ran: zfs get mounted,mountpoint,canmount server, and canmount=on etc. If this was not the case and it was empty, do you think if I ran: zfs set mountpoint=/server server, that might fix the problem? I'm sure unfortunately I'll find myself in the situation where I have to try it. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, zfs wont mount it if it has no `mountpoint` property.   Set the mount point to wherever you want it (`/server` is fine), and then mount it with `zfs mount -a`.   btw, ping me with `@cas` if you reply, I won't get notified if you don't. It's only by chance that I checked my comments just now.

Comment: BTW, what distro are you running? Did you install zfs as a package, or compile it yourself?  If a package, did you also install the distro's package for auto-importing zpools and auto-mounting zfs datasets?  e.g. on debian, that's done in the `zfs-initramfs` package, which adds the necessary scripts and commands to the initrd used at boot time.

Comment: @cas, oh sorry. Thanks. Okay, so `zfs set canmount=on server` or `zfs set mountpoint=/server`  then `zfs mount -a` the pool was mounted on boot each time I tried on the weekend, so only twice it hasn't been there. Does this mean that /server exists as a location in the OS, irrespective of the ZFS system? Even though it was created using ZFS? I am using MX Linux (debian based) and I installed ZFS via the .deb files, so regarding the inconsistent zpool visibility on boot, you may have a very good point about the `zfs-initramfs` package, I'll look into this. Thanks again!

Comment: yeah, a mountpoint (MP) is just a directory, a location in the filesystem tree where another fs can be mounted.  The MP for a ZFS dataset is created with mkdir by `zfs mount` if it doesn't already exist.  And, like any other directory used as an MP for any fs, it stays around when the fs is unmounted.   The standard `mount` command used for other filesystems doesn't create the MP dir automatically unless you use the `-o X-mount.mkdir` option (without that option, it will just print an error message of "mount point does not exist").

Comment: BTW, because an MP is just a directory, if there are any files etc in that directory when another fs is mounted on top of it (whether ZFS or ext4 or some other fs type), those files will be hidden and inaccessible for the duration of the mount.   That's why, for example, it's important for scripts that cp/rsync lots of files to an MP called, e.g., `/backup` to check whether there's an fs mounted there, otherwise they'll be copied to the parent fs (/ in this case). it's easy to completely fill that parent fs if you're not careful, especially with a recursive copy that includes /backup itself.

Comment: @cas, thanks for the very informative explanations in your replies. I installed the 'zfs-initramfs' package (which wasn't installed). Seemed to install fine. I didn't get a chance to re-boot after installing, but in the only instance I did boot up again last night the zpool was already mounted, so I didn't have an opportunity to try setting the mountpoint as per your earlier post. Is there anything you suggest I check now that 'zfs-initramfs' is installed? It would be nice to get some confirmation whether it is or isn't fixed. Thanks again

Comment: if it's working (i.e. /server is mounted when you reboot) then there's nothing more you need to do.  If it's not mounted properly, then run `zfs set mountpoint=/server server` followed by `zfs mount -a`.    It should now be mounted.  Reboot to verify that it's going to be auto-mounted when the machine boots up.   BTW any future datasets that you create (e.g. with `zfs create server/mydata`) will have their mountpoint default to under the parent (e.g. server/mydata will mount as /server/mydata) unless you override it with `zfs set mountpoint=`

Comment: Also, if you want to move the data you already copied onto /server into their own datasets, you can  just create a new dataset and mv the files into it.  Note that this will not be a quick rename, it will be a copy and delete because a new dataset is a new filesystem (same as if you were moving files to a diferent disk or partition).    e.g. if you have a directory called `/server/foo` and want to turn that into its own dataset: `cd /server ; mv foo foo.old; zfs create server/foo; mv foo.old/* foo/; rmdir foo.old`.

Comment: If there are any hidden dotfiles (e.g. like `.config` or `.hidden`) in the top-level of `foo.old/`, you'll need to run `shopt -o dotglob` before the `mv` command to make sure that they are matched by the `foo.old/*` glob.   and `shopt +o dotglob` afterwards to turn it back off.

Comment: and when you create new datasets, you can set different properties on each one.  e.g. there's no point in enabling compression on a dataset which contains mostly compressed files like audio or video.   or you might want to set a different recordsize if you're creating a dataset specifically for a mysql or postgresql db (e.g. a recordsize of 16k or 32k instead of the default 128k greatly improves performance for mysql).   Similarly, if you're running VMs with .qcow2 files, you could create a dataset for them with the same recordsize as the .qcow2 file's clustersize.

Comment: @cas, thanks again for the replies! I take your point about 'the proof is in the pudding' regarding if it mounts on boot it works, it's just that I was hoping to see some system variable or some product only `zfs-initramfs` would modify, change, which would explain why it was sporadically working previously (hopefully consistent now). I think I'll use RSYNC from now on rather than mv. This is admittedly a dumb question, but once you create your first dataset in the zpool, you're free to create sub-directories in it and dump files into them as normal in any file system like ext4? Cheers

Comment: yes, you can create files or sub-directories in a dataset whenever you like.  that's kind of a crucial feature for a file-system, right? :-)     A dataset is basically a separate filesystem on the zpool (similar to a formatted fs, like ext4 or xfs, on a drive or partition or LVM volume) which can have its own specific properties (like mountpoint, compression, record size, or encryption - see `man zfsprops` for details on properties).

Comment: and, as i mentioned previously, a zpool always has at least one dataset at the top-level of the pool....you can put files or directories directly in that (same as any other dataset), but I prefer to leave the top-level empty and have my files in datasets underneath it.   as well as allowing for different properties for each dataset, it makes it easier to manage snapshots and backups etc for only a subset of my data at a time instead of all of it at once.

Comment: @cas, Good news and bad news. I booted up and the zpool was missing again. Using the `get` command: "cannot open 'server': dataset does not exist". I couldn't `set` `canmount`. `Status` & `list` said "no pools available". I'm not using systemd so I don't think I can use systemctl. The good news is, using `import` I was able to find the zpool and mount it. However, it means `zfs-initramfs` didn't solve the issue. Best regards and thanks